# How do I change colour of a java swing button on click via a lambda function

Tags: java, swing

So I have just got into java swing and cannot find how I would change the colour within a lambda function, I imagine it will have something to do with getting the source or maybe even just making the button variable at the top of the class so I can access it from anywhere in the code.

Here is my window class:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class window {
    JFrame frame;
    window(String title){
        this.frame = new JFrame(title);
        JButton button = new JButton("Text");
        button.addActionListener(x-> System.out.println(x.getSource()));
        this.frame.setSize(550,550);
        button.setBounds(550/2-75,550/2-75,150,50);

        this.frame.add(button);
        this.frame.setLayout(null);
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and my main class:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window win = new window("Hi");
    }
}
```

I would like for the button to change colour on click.

Comment: Implement java.awt.event.ActionEvent on your window class and (write) override the method "public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)" then notify the button has an event  using the method buttonid.addActionListener(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would override the `actionPerformed` in `addActionListener` method for this. Example from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315816/17210223):

```java
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // the source here refers to the object that provoked this method to occur
    JButton sourceBtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
    sourceBtn.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

You might want to read Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on this, which will strengthen your understanding here.

Thanks to [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675) for correcting me on my phrasing.

Comment: `addActionListener` is a method, it does not contain other methods, you cannot override a method of it - maybe you meant override/implement the `actionPerformed` method of `ActionListener`